# Which column attributes in a MySQL statement can specified in a CREATE TABLE / ALTER TABLE statement?

Tags: mysql, create-table, information-schema

**Task at Hand :** Need to create  tables in MySQL basis a dump from the columns table from Information.Schema of another database.  I do not have access to the original DB or the DB architect. I would like to know which of the following attributes found in extracts from the Information_Schema of the original database **CAN** be specified in CREATE TABLE statements. The objective is to create a Tables which are ditto as per the original.

**Problem at Hand:** I understand that some of these attributes are specified by the user while creating tables while some may be calculated by MySQL from the data in tables. While I am reading and understanding on each of these attributes, I am unable to quickly ascertain which of the attributes listed below are calculated by MySQL and not user specified and hence can be ignored while writing CREATE TABLE statements.

CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
NUMERIC_PRECISION
NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
NUMERIC_SCALE
DATETIME_PRECISION
CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG
CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA
CHARACTER_SET_NAME
COLLATION_CATALOG
COLLATION_SCHEMA
COLLATION_NAME
DOMAIN_CATALOG
DOMAIN_SCHEMA
DOMAIN_NAME

Comment: The `information_schema`.`columns` table won't give you everything you'll need if you want to recreate the original create table statement. You'll also need  `information_schema`.`tables` which will give you the engine (probably the default innodb, but just to be sure), `statistics` will give you the keys and `key_column_usage` and `referential_constraints` any foreign key definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please read the [**MySQL Manual Page**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html)

For `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` and similar character (non-`TEXT`) columns; the **CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH** value is just that;

```
CREATE TABLE pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20),
   species VARCHAR(20), sex CHAR(1), birth DATE, death DATE);
                  ^^^^          ^^^ 
                   This is the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH value of this column.
```

**CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH** should be the same as **CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH**, except for multi-byte character sets.

For multi-byte characters sets you should [probably be using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236)  `utf8mb4_` sets. So the
**CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH** may be **CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH** x 4 (for 4-byte full UTF-8; note that `utf8_` MySQL character sets/collations are **3-byte** only). While this value is auto-generated upon table creation, if you're building these data sets manually you *might* need to calculate this one yourself.

Which character set you use will also relate to which **CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA**
and **CHARACTER_SET_NAME** is set. For example `utf8mb4_general_ci` would

For **NUMERIC_*** values; please [read here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232901/why-is-the-value-of-numeric-scale-column-in-information-schema-columns-table-for)

- **COLLATION_***  (ex [Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html)) stuff is user set but if not user set then database and/or table defaults are used.
- **CHARACTER_SET_*** (ex [Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html)) stuff is user set but if not user set then database and/or table defaults are used.
- **DATETIME_PRECISION** is database/OS set and is not set on `TABLE CREATE`
- **DOMAIN_*** values are not found on the MySQL Manual and seem to be invalid

## So;

CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH - User set `*`
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH - Auto generated, from User set/default details (`*`)
NUMERIC_PRECISION - User set
NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX - User set for specific `spacial`-type columns
NUMERIC_SCALE - User set
DATETIME_PRECISION - System set
CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG - System set catalogue of possible values. 
CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA - The generated Schema of possible values from the Catalogue
CHARACTER_SET_NAME - User set but defaults to MySQL /  Db default values `*` 
COLLATION_CATALOG - System set catalogue of possible values. 
COLLATION_SCHEMA - The generated Schema of possible values from the Catalogue
COLLATION_NAME - User set but defaults to MySQL /  Db default values `*` 
DOMAIN_CATALOG - Unknown. no records of this type. 
DOMAIN_SCHEMA - Unknown. no records of this type. 
DOMAIN_NAME - Unknown. no records of this type.